# Why does my `zipAll` give OutOfMemoryError and how do I fix it?

Tags: kotlin, sequence

I am trying to write a good `zipAll` function -- not like Scala's function, but rather like C++'s `zip_view`: just Kotlin's zip with an arbitrary number of sequences iterated in parallel, length equal to shortest.

I came up with:

```
fun <T> zipAll(vararg seq: Sequence<T>): Sequence<List<T>> {
    return sequence { 
        while (seq.all { it.iterator().hasNext() }) 
            yield(seq.map { it.take(1).first() }) 
    }
}

fun main() {
    val s = sequenceOf(1,2,3)
    val s2 = sequenceOf(3,4,5,6)    
    println(zipAll(s, s2).toList())
}
```

But [Kotlin Playground gives](https://pl.kotl.in/JeZX-UIE7) (edit: using more complete stacktrace from my local IntelliJ Idea)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3512)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3481)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:237)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:244)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:454)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:816)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the sequence generation stops when the provided function returns null but in this case this is infinite... that is what my  understanding says.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee This is true for `generateSequence`, but not for `sequence`. That one should end when it can no longer yield anything: `sequence { yield(1) }` is valid...

Comment: you never access the `.next` in the iterator, so the result of `it.iterator().hasNext()` will always be true, essentially a `while(true)` scenario

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee but you're actually right that an infinite sequence is being generated, so the stopping condition of the loop doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexT Thanks, ow, I somehow thought the sequence itself was being consumed by `take` and `iterator` would always point to the "current" element (that which `take(1)` will take), but it seems it doesn't work this way. Probably best to only use the iterator, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Sequence.iterator()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/iterator.html) doesn't necessarily create an iterator for the *rest* of the `Sequence`. For sequences that can be iterated multiple times, like the ones you create with `sequenceOf`, `iterator` gives you a brand new iterator, starting from the beginning of the sequence. And for sequences that cannot be iterated multiple times, calling `iterator` a second time *will* throw an exception.

Therefore, the `while` condition is never false, and you end up creating an infinite sequence.

You should keep track of the iterators of each sequence:

```
fun <T> zipAll(vararg seq: Sequence<T>): Sequence<List<T>> {
    return sequence {
        val iterators = seq.map { it.iterator() }
        while (iterators.all { it.hasNext() })
            yield(iterators.map { it.next() })
    }
}
```